# How can I make tmux use "C-b C-b C-b" to get into the 3rd nested tmux session?

Tags: command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

In tmux I get into the 2nd nested session by using `C-b C-b` (Ctrl+b twice). But if I have a 3rd nested session, I can't use `C-b C-b C-b` to get to the 3rd nested session. Somehow if I spam `C-b`, sometimes it can get to the 3rd nested session. What's happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use 1*2*2 (=4) control-b's to get a control-b to the third level tmux with the default bindings, and 1*2*2*2 (=8) to get it to a fourth level tmux, and in general 2<sup>n-1</sup> to get to the n<sup>th</sup> tmux.

"What is happening?". All the control-b's are read by the first level tmux. The first one is taken to introduce a command sequence. The second one says to run the command to send a control b to the application. The third starts a sequence and the forth runs the command to send a second control-b to the application. Now the application is the second level tmux. As a result of you typing 4 control-b's the first level tmux has sent 2 control-b's to the second level. The first of these starts a command sequence, and the second runs the command to send a control-b to the third level tmux.

If you are going to do a lot of this deeply nested tmux usage I suggest you look into adding some custom binds to send the 2, 4, 8, 16 etc control-b characters. For example

```
    bind-key -T prefix C-g send -N 1 C-b
    bind-key -T prefix C-h send -N 2 C-b
    bind-key -T prefix C-l send -N 4 C-b
```

You can put these into your tmux configuration file, or else enter them at the first level tmux by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>p</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>C</kbd><kbd>-</kbd><kbd>h</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>etc. This will make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>g</kbd>/<kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd>  send commands to the second/third/fourth level tmux.

An alternative which I mention for completeness is to use different prefix keys in the different tmux. I don't recommend it, it allows too many opportunities to get confused.

Comment: This worked for me: `bind-key -T prefix C-c send -N 2 C-b`, `bind-key -T prefix C-v send -N 3 C-`. The examples you gave above don't seem to go to the second and third level tmux, they skip some. (`C-b C-g` goes to the 3rd level, and `C-b C-h` goes to the 5th level)

Comment: True, edited the response. I forgot that I needed one less doubling of control-B as I didn't need to pass it through the first level tmux, the first level tmux was generating it.